# is there a maximum number of inserts that can be run in a batch sql script?

Tags: sql, batch-file

I have a series of simple `"Insert INTO"` type statements but after running about 3 or 4 of them the script stops and i get empty sets when i try selecting from the appropriate tables....aside from my specific code...i wonder whether there is an ideal way of running multiple insert type queries.

Right now i just have a txt file saved as a`.sql` with normal `sql` commands separated by `";"`

Comment: Want to add the sql you are doing in your script?  That might assist people in suggesting a best practice to you.  Thanks.

Comment: You may want to mention what database you're using.  On the face of it, it should be working, although the rows wouldn't be visible until until after some kind of commit (implicit or explicit) took place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Maximum Capacity Specifications for SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx)

Max Batch size = 65,536 * Network Packet Size

However I doubt that Max Batch size is your problem.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not. however, if it stops after 3 or 4 inserts, it's a good bet there's an error in the 3rd or 4th insert. Depending on which SQL engine you use, there are different ways of making it report errors during and after operations.

Additionally, if you have lots of inserts, it's a good idea to wrap them inside a transaction - this basically buffers all the insert commands until it sees the end command for the transaction, and then commit everything to your table. That way, if something goes wrong, your database doesn't get polluted with data that needs to first be deleted again. More importantly, every insert without a transaction counts as a single transaction, which makes them really slow - Doing 100 inserts inside a transaction can be as fast as doing two or three normal inserts.

Comment: Could also be lag in writing the log entries for the data being inserted.